# Does Firestore in Datastore mode support array-contains-any queries like Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Cloud Firestore has documentation for [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) queries. However, the Firestore in Datastore mode [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#in) doesn't show any documentation for array-contains. It only has `IN` documentation.

My question is, does Firestore in Datastore mode support array contain queries too? Perhaps it does but the syntax is the same as for `IN` queries? Take this example:

```
Query<Entity> query =
    Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
        .setKind("Task")
        .setFilter(PropertyFilter.in("tag", ListValue.of("learn", "study")))
        .build();
```

If the `tag` property is an array, will this return entities that where the array contains "learn" or "study"?

Similar to this example in Cloud Firestore?

```
CollectionReference tasksRef = db.collection("Task");
tasksRef.whereArrayContainsAny("tag", Arrays.asList("learn", "study"));
```

As a side question, are there three (3) Firestore products now? Cloud Firestore, Firestore in Native mode, Firestore in Datastore mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there three (3) Firestore products now? Cloud Firestore, Firestore in Native mode, Firestore in Datastore mode?

No, there are only two. Cloud Firestore and Firestore in native mode are the same.

> Cloud Firestore has documentation for `array-contains-any` queries. However, the Firestore in Datastore mode documentation doesn't show any documentation for array-contains.

Yes, Firestore provides indeed an [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) query. However, you're asking if Firestore in Datastore mode contains an `array-contains` and not an `array-contains-any` query. There's a big difference between these queries. Please note that Firestore (in Native mode) provides both, [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) and [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) queries. On the other hand, Firestore in Datastore mode doesn't provide an `array-contains-any` query, but it offers the capability to [search an array for a specific value using equality filters](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#array_values).

> If the tag property is an array, will these return entities where the array contains "learn" or "study"?

If the "tag" field is a String, then it will check against the values in the list. If the "tag" field is an array, it will not check each element in the array against each element in the list. Most likely an Exception will be thrown.

If you want to benefit from queries like `array-contains`, `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any`, then I recommend you use [Firestore (in Native mode)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer. I didn't have enough room here, so I updated my question with a follow up question in regards to your answer, if you could please take a look.

Comment: Asking a follow-up question should be typically a new post. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you. I also rolled back your question to the initial state so it cannot create confusion for future visitors.

Comment: However, to be brief, I don't think you can simulate that, as those queries represent different concepts. Let me see the new question, maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: Gotcha, I made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77464420

Comment: @Micro I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.