# How does multiple equality filters on an array field in Firestore (in Datastore mode) work?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

The Firestore (in Datastore mode) [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#array_values) says:

> Datastore mode indexes each unique array property value once per index. Thus to query if an array contains a value use an equality filter.

This statement implies that you can only query for one value with an equality filter. However, there is also this example, with the following note that says:

> Unlike inequality filters, multiple equality filters can be used to
> query for entities that contain a set of values.

```
Query<Entity> query =
        Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
            .setKind("Task")
            .setFilter(
                CompositeFilter.and(
                    PropertyFilter.eq("tag", "fun"), PropertyFilter.eq("tag", "programming")))
            .build();
```

I'm confused about what this query can do. Does this mean that this query will:

a) Return Task entities where the "tag" field is an array and the array ONLY contains the values "fun" and "programming"

OR/AND

b) Return Task entities where the "tag" field is an array with many different values (e.g. `["fun", "programming", "algo", "interview"]`), but at least two of them are "fun" and "programming"?

The example from the documentation appears to be similar to the [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) example from Firestore, but it isn't clear as to what its limits/abilities are.

Comment: It will return entities where the `tag`  field is an array with many different values,but at least two of them are `fun` and `programming`.It does not require to only have `fun` and `programming`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided in your question uses two equality filters. So the query is searching for entities that have the values `fun` and `programming` in the `tag` array property. Remember, the [CompositeFilter.and()](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-composite-filter) method combines the two `PropertyFilter.eq()` filters into a single filter that requires both conditions to be met. So it's an `AND` operation and **not** an `OR`. However, the `tag` can contain multiple values, not only those two.

Comment: Thank you. Are you allowed to use an `CompositeFilter.or()` in the above query (with everything else the same)?

Comment: As far as I can see, you can combine filters with a logical `OR`. Here are the [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/java-datastore/blob/154b99d5cc802f0f327703a3e96487b3c3e042b3/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/datastore/filters/OrFilterQuery.java#L42) and the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries). However, I did not test this with arrays.